# need help on installing eth-brownie on windows 10

Tags: installation, bootcamp, chainlink

While installing eth-brownie via "pip install eth-brownie" on vscode terminal, I am getting the error below:

- I already chose the default terminal CMD
- I already tried installing the required VS CODE build tools

Please help, thanks!

Error:

```
Running setup.py install for cytoolz ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\simpl\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\simpl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rncdvkky\\cytoolz_dc3d86c874b8423fa2581a6b8be8ab33\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\simpl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rncdvkky\\cytoolz_dc3d86c874b8423fa2581a6b8be8ab33\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\simpl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q40t7042\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\simpl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\cytoolz'
         cwd: C:\Users\simpl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rncdvkky\cytoolz_dc3d86c874b8423fa2581a6b8be8ab33\
    Complete output (50 lines):
    ALERT: Cython not installed.  Building without Cython.
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\operator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\cpython.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dicttoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_embedded_sigs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_functoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_inspect_args.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_itertoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_none_safe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_recipes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_tlz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    running build_ext
    building 'cytoolz.dicttoolz' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\simpl\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\simpl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rncdvkky\\cytoolz_dc3d86c874b8423fa2581a6b8be8ab33\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\simpl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rncdvkky\\cytoolz_dc3d86c874b8423fa2581a6b8be8ab33\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\simpl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q40t7042\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\simpl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\cytoolz' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: can you try installing all the pipx/brownie stuff from the command prompt (outside VSCode), making sure you right click and choose 'run as administrator'?

Comment: Can you please follow this video exactly start to finish? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcI1_e38BWs

Answer (score 0):

You need to install
***Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater***
then proceed it will work

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. Despite having Visual C++ 14.0+, still getting the same error while trying to install brownie.

Can someone guide with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same error even after installing vs tool (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/). Therefore, I found conda installation.
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cytoolz